# Is there an API for Google Appengine for Excel import / export ?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying with csv upload but because of comma in address field the values are not loaded correctly.

Comment: As [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) have a clear specification : **Fields with embedded commas or double-quote characters must be quoted.**. So the simpliest solution could be to use a CSV, with proper format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using appengine python the standard [csv package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html%20CSV%20Package) is an option. It lets you configure things like quoting (See Dialects & Formatting Parameters section of the above link).

If you save the csv out of excel, it should match the format it expects by default.